# Custom block for display of scorm interactions

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I have developed custom block which extract scorm interactions, elements like x.start.time, core.cmi.lesson_status
My question is whether the result is displayed for logged in users only. Here is my code.

class block_scormtest extends block_base {

```
function init() {
    $this->title = get_string('pluginname', 'block_scormtest');
}
function get_content()  {
    global $DB;

    if ($this->content  !== NULL) {
        return $this->content;
    }

    $content = '';
  
    $courses = $DB->get_records('scorm_scoes_track', ['element' => 'cmi.core.lesson_status']);
    foreach ($courses as $course) {
        $content  = $course->attempt.  '     '.userdate($course->timemodified, get_string('strftimerecentfull')). '  '. $course->value. '<br>';
    }

 $this->content = new stdClass;
$this->content->text = $content;
        
}
         
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to specify the user id if you want a specific user

Add the global `$USER` object at the top eg:

```
global $DB, $USER;
```

Then use something like this for the SQL - this is for elements containing `cmi.core.lesson_status` or `x.start.time`

```
[$elemsql, $elemparams] = $DB->get_in_or_equal(['cmi.core.lesson_status', 'x.start.time'], SQL_PARAMS_NAMED);

$sql = "SELECT sst.id, c.id AS courseid, c.fullname AS coursename, s.id AS scormid, s.name AS scormname, sst.attempt, sst.element, sst.value
        FROM {scorm_scoes_track} sst
        JOIN {scorm} s ON s.id = sst.scormid
        JOIN {course} c ON c.id = s.course
        WHERE sst.userid = :userid
        AND sst.element {$elemsql}";

$params = array_merge(['userid' => $USER->id], $elemparams);

$scoes = $DB->get_records_sql($sql, $params);
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for this Russell.

I'm looking to edit the logic so that the logged in user can only see the records that they themselves have created for scorm interactions(x.start.time, cmi.interactions_0.student_response, cmi.interactions_1.student_response, cmi.core.lesson_status)

Thanks again for looking into it.

Comment: No probs - yep the global `$USER` object is the currently logged in user, so the SQL above will only return their records

Answer (score 0):

I am new to this LMS development, so I am trying to figure out a few custom blocks. My question again is related to scorm interactions. I have added this sql query

SELECT scc.userid AS User, sct.name AS Name, scc.scoid AS SCORM_ID, sct.module AS Module, scc.value AS Sale_amount, sct.value AS Loan_amount

FROM

(SELECT u.id AS userid, st.scoid AS scoid, st.value AS value

FROM prefix_course AS c

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm AS sc ON sc.course=c.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm_scoes_track AS st ON st.scormid=sc.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id=st.userid

WHERE st.element='cmi.interactions_0.student_response') AS scc

LEFT JOIN

(SELECT c.fullname Course, sc.name AS module, st.scoid AS scoid, u.id AS userid, u.firstname name, st.attempt as Attempt, st.value AS value

FROM prefix_course AS c

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm AS sc ON sc.course=c.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_scorm_scoes_track AS st ON st.scormid=sc.id

LEFT JOIN prefix_user AS u ON u.id=st.userid

WHERE st.element='cmi.interactions_1.student_response') AS sct

ON sct.scoid=scc.scoid

AND sct.userid=scc.userid

ORDER BY scc.userid

to generate reports on loan amounts and sale amounts. Now I want to display it in the form of custom block showing only the total loan amount and sale amount by the user that they have made. This is a little tricky. For example: here in this screenshot, for the admin user, the total loan amount should be 17800 and sale amount: 116000

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pa6ep.png)

Is this possible in any way by using SELECT sum(value) WHERE element='cmi.interactions_0.student_response' sale amount= sum of student response